# How do I do multiplication in a php multi dimention array

Tags: php, arrays

how can i show php array multiplying in loop
I have to show in the foreach so that I can add mysql

```
$data = [
[
  "id" => "3202",
  "total" => "5"

],[
  "id" => "3190",
  "total" => "2"

],[
  "id" => "3199",
  "total" => "5"
]
];


foreach($data as $v){
    //$v["total"]*
    //output = 5x2x5= 50
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_column` and `array_product` in this problem:

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['id' => '3202','total' => '5'],
    ['id' => '3190','total' => '2'],
    ['id' => '3199','total' => '5']
];

$total = array_column($data, 'total');

$product = array_product($total);

printf('The product of total: %s', $product);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['id' => '3202','total' => '5'],
    ['id' => '3190','total' => '2'],
    ['id' => '3199','total' => '5']
];

$total = 1; // empty product
$output = [];

foreach($data as $v) {
    $total *= $v['total'];
    $output[] = $v['total'];
}

echo implode('x', $output) . '= ' . $total; // 5x2x5= 50
```

Might want to also add logic to check if the $data is empty first with `count($data)`, then when the list is empty, output a message instead.